# includepdf error message cannot find file

Tags: packages, pdfpages

When I try to compile the file, I get this error message:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={-}]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

> Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `-'. \includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}

When I change `\includepdf[pages=-]{file.pdf}` to `\includepdf[pages={1}]{file.pdf}` it will print the first page or any other page I want. It also does not work and show the error message when I try to print pages 7-11, so anytime I put - sign I get the message.

Does anyone know, why is that and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a full example?  That's the correct syntax and should work.  Is it possible your editor is changing `-` to some other character?

Comment: Did you try to compile via command line (rather than via a GUI) ? Result ?

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={-}]{file.pdf}

\end{document}

Comment: "Did you try to compile via command line (rather than via a GUI) ? Result?"
 No I did not

Comment: try without `\usepackage[czech]{babel} ` if that is the issue add `\shorthandoff{-}` just before the image inclusion to make `-` safe

Comment: Is it possible, that is is because of the \usepackage[czech]{babel} package? Because it seems to me, that this causes the problem, but still I do not know, how to solve it

Comment: "try without \usepackage[czech]{babel} if that is the issue add \shorthandoff{-} just before the image inclusion to make - safe"

-- Yes, this both works, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `-` is made into an active shorthand character by the `czech` babel option, you can use

```
\shorthandoff{-}
```

Just before the pdf inclusion to make `-` safe again. Normally this is inside a group so `-` will regain its `babel` meaning, or you could use `\shorthandon` to explicitly reset it.

Comment: Most of the times I get amazed how @david-carlisle spots the problem, saving many hours of my life by the his answers.